# What is the proper and best way to drain and vent this bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, drain-waste-vent

The green lines are existing vent for shower.
The black lines are proposed bathroom sink drain and p-trap.
The red lines are option 1 for vent for bathroom sink.
The blue lines are option 2 for vent for bathroom sink.
All pipes are 2 inches.

Since the existing horizontal vent for the shower(green lines) are not 6 in. above FLR (flood level rim) of the sink I believe the red or blue lines are required. Is one option better than the other or violate code?

[image: Bathroom drain options]